# In Star Wars Episode IV what made the moaning sound that scared the Sand People?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

What made the moaning sound that scared away the Sand People? Most people think that it's either a bantha that got scared of Ben-Kenobi coming, or Kenobi used the Force to make a sound.

Comment: Before unregistering it woulda been nice she'd accepted my answer :(

Comment: @Rocket Unregisterd merely means Victoria didn't register, but unless she deletes the cookie _and_ looses her email address, which IIRC is still required for posting, she can still return to do so... Anyway, I'd say the upvotes speak for themselves

Comment: @Zommuter yes lol it was just for the badge LOL Im a big baby :P

Answer (score 53):

Obi-Wan Kenobi mimicked a [Lesser krayt dragon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Krayt_dragon) hunting cry when he scared the
Tusken Raiders away from Luke Skywalker.

> **Luke Skywalker:** "What made the Sand People leave?"
>
> **Obi-Wan Kenobi:** *"I imitated the hunting cry of a krayt dragon. Their
>   imaginations did the rest and they took to their heels."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars : Radio Dramatization : A New Hope](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_(radio))</sup></sub>

There are even two different versions of this cry; the theatrical version and the Bluray release version [here](http://youtu.be/-yxuDU8gims) for comparison

---

Although a live Krayt Dragon is never seen in A New Hope (or any other Star Wars movie), C3PO comes across a partial skeleton of a **Greater** Krayt Dragon while he's out wandering in the desert.

[image]

Comment: This. Luke also does the same thing in the Timothy Zahn novel, *Heir to the Empire*. It appears to be less a Jedi thing, and more a Tatooinian thing.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Well I always thought that Obi Wan learn this skill by himself and then, either he teaches it to Luke or Luke teaches himself. I think the origin of this sound made by Jedi or Tatooinian is another question... you've opened back my curiosity :P

Comment: Obi-Wan definitely doesn't have time to teach it to Luke before the former dies. That implies that either Luke taught himself afterwards, or it's something he already knew. Either way, it's not definitively Jedi or Tatooinian.

Comment: @JamesSheridan I know the time between he meet luke and he dies is short.. but he is still able to communicate with Luke by his *Phantom state* and this is how I think he taught Luke. As about when this I'm not sure. I know Luke communicates a lot with Obi Wan's *Phantom* between episod 5 and 6 But like you said, he might already knew it or he taught himself.

Comment: To clarify, Kenobi imitated the call of a LESSER Krayt Dragon - the more common one that looks like a giant version of the horned lizard. The skeleton seen in the desert is from the rarer GREATER Krayt Dragon, which looks more like a plesiosaur with six flippers. Minor nitpick, but might be worth adding to the answer.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - It's not a generic Tattooine thing, it's an Obi-Wan thing. He was involved in a group of people who invented using the call to scare off Sand People and learned that trick (from Miller's "Kenobi" novel)

Comment: It likely wouldn't have been difficult for Luke to figure out. He knew that Obi-Wan had done it, thus he knew it was possible. He also knew enough about the force to add a little oomph to it to make it realistic (which Obi-Wan obviously did as well).

I think it's a Jedi thing to make it sound realistic enough that it doesn't sound like a cat trying to mimic a cow, and a Tatooinian thing because that's where the Krayt Dragons live. You have to know what they sound like to imitate them.

Comment: Re the C3PO image: is that from the original version or the "Special Edition" from the 90s? I don't remember seeing it...

Comment: @PerLundberg it is in both I think, the scene just after R2D2 take off and C3P0 decide to go the other way on Tatooine

Comment: For the record, the radio dramatization is no longer considered a fully canon source of information for Star Wars. Since this scene didn't occur in the films, it's considered part of the "legends" canon; http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/2015/01/the-new-star-wars-canon-guide/

Comment: @Richard :D excellent thank you for this AWESOME link :D

Answer (score 8):

This is covered in the official <s>Alan Dean Foster</s> George Lucas novelisation of [Star Wars Episode IV : A New Hope.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_%28novel%29)

> Placing both hands over his mouth in a peculiar fashion, Kenobi
>   inhaled deeply and let out an unearthly howl that made Luke jump.
>   “That ought to keep any laggards running for a while yet,” the old man
>   concluded with satisfaction.
>
> **“That’s a krayt dragon call!” Luke gaped in astonishment. “How did you
>   do that?”**
>
> “I’ll show you sometime, son. It’s not too hard. Just takes the right
>   attitude, a set of well-used vocal cords, and a lot of wind. Now, if
>   you were an Imperial bureaucrat, I could teach you right off, but
>   you’re not.” He scanned the cliff-spine again. “And I don’t think this
>   is the time or place for it.”